# why Apache's setEnvIf doesn't set correct header and how to debug it

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, apache-2.4, regex

I have the following in my `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    SetEnvIf Origin "http(s)?:\/\/(www\.)?(inreado\.local|testenv\.inreado\.com|inreado\.com)$" AccessControlAllowOrigin=$0$1
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{AccessControlAllowOrigin}e env=AccessControlAllowOrigin
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true
</IfModule>
```

I'm trying to set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header if host is one of the three allowed domains specified in the regexp. But it never does set this header. Here is the request and response:

REQUEST

```
GET http://inreado.local:8080/ HTTP/1.1
Host: inreado.local:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en,en-US;q=0.8,ru;q=0.6
```

RESPONSE

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Sun, 22 Mar 2015 09:44:17 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.10 (Win64) PHP/5.6.3
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.3
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

I've tested regexp against `http://inreado.local` string [here](https://regex101.com/) and it should match, so I don't understand where the problem is.

**Update**

```
SetEnvIf Origin "http(s)?://(www\.)?(inreado\.local:8080)$" AccessControlAllowOrigin=$1$2
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{AccessControlAllowOrigin}e env=AccessControlAllowOrigin
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE :** Obviously the first thing to do is to send the `Origin` header in your request ...

Your regex is `"http(s)?:\/\/(www\.)?(inreado\.local|testenv\.inreado\.com|inreado\.com)$"`

But I believe it doesn't match at all because you need to add the port to this URL regex (since `inreado.local` and `inreado.local:8080` are two distinct origins). Thus your header directive is skipped since the env variable is not set.

So :

- Add the relevant `Origin` header in your request.
- Add the port to your regex.

By the way escaping slashes is not necessary in your regex.

Comment: @Maximus Well, didn't see that but it looks like you are not sending the `Origin` header at all in your request ...

Comment: thanks a lot!!! missing `origin` in request caused the problem. By the way, with `AccessControlAllowOrigin=$1$2` `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header returns empty string, but with `$0$1` it works OK.

Comment: Thanks, I've figure that out myself. However, I also have [this question](http://serverfault.com/questions/677405/why-apache-returns-error-message-in-body-while-returning-200-status-code), maybe you'll be able to help here. Thanks!