# why apache returns error message in body while returning 200 status code

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, apache-2.4

I've configured Apache to return 200 on all requests that made with `OPTIONS` verb:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]
```

The Apache indeed returns status `200 OK`, yet the body contains an error message:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 22 Mar 2015 16:38:10 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.10 (Win64) PHP/5.6.3
Content-Length: 492
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>200 OK</title>
</head><body>
<h1>OK</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error or
misconfiguration and was unable to complete
your request.</p>
<p>Please contact the server administrator at 
 admin@example.com to inform them of the time this error occurred,
 and the actions you performed just before this error.</p>
<p>More information about this error may be available
in the server error log.</p>
</body></html>
```

Why so? Is configuration not correct?

Comment: Check your error log.

Comment: There is nothing there except for this warning: `[:error] [pid 4496:tid 988] [client 127.0.0.1:56492] PHP Deprecated:  Automatically populating $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. To avoid this warning set 'always_populate_raw_post_data' to '-1' in php.ini and use the php://input stream instead. in Unknown on line 0`. Do you think it can cause the error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Maximus, you must use "204-No Content" as response code.

Details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32146203/2397394

Answer (score 0):

Similar to a [soft 404](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404#Soft_404), this looks to be a [soft 500](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/custom-error.html). I would suggest check you apache configuration for the settings noted in the link to see if that might be your issue.

Comment: sorry, can you please elaborate more about the approach you suggested